# Cooldown for Slowmo

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know the problem is simple, but I'm new to Unity and don't understand how to do it. I would like for there to be a delay between the ability to cause time dilation and the deceleration itself to last no more than a certain time.

```
void FixedUpdate ()    
{

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Mouse1))    
    {    
        Time.timeScale = 0.1f;    
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 0.01f;    
    }    
    else    
    {    
        Time.timeScale = 1f;    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code i would totally suggest you to watch and study more tutorials on unity. I will still write down a simple delay logic with comments.

```
private float _lastTimeAbilityUsed;
private float _abilityCooldown = 2f; // cooldown for 2 seconds

private void Update()    
{
    if(_lastTimeAbilityUsed < Time.time - _abilityCooldown) return; // if not enough time has passed, returning

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Mouse1))    
    {    
        _lastTimeAbilityUsed  = Time.time; // saving the time when ability is used
    }
}
```